# not exact result of sum in python 3

Tags: python, bigint

I make functions of sum from *1* to last number as follows

```
def sum_way1(last_num):
    sum_val = 0
    for num in range(1, last_num+1):
        sum_val=sum_val+num
    return sum_val

def sum_way2(last_num):
    return int((last_num*(last_num+1))/2)
```

But the result as follows:

- sum from 1 to 10000000000 : 50000000005000000000, execution time: 268.999 sec
- sum from 1 to 10000000000 : 50000000005000003584, execution time: 0.000 sec

The result of `sum_way2` function is not exact.
Please let me know why I cannot get exact result of `sum_way2` function?

Exact result:

- sum from 1 to 10000000000 : 50000000005000000000, execution time: 268.999 sec
- sum from 1 to 10000000000 : 50000000005000000000, execution time: 0.000 sec

Comment: Because not each number can represented exactly. Same goes for 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 in our (base-10) number system; is that 0.99999 (0.33333 + 0.33333 + 0.33333) or 1? What people usually refer to is: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: A bit of a diversion, but the "1/3 in base 10" situation is slightly different. 1/3 isn't representable in base 10, because there are no ints a, n such that `a/10^n = 1/3`. But here, the results of OP's calculation are all in fact integers. (Multiplying two consecutive integers gives an even number, so halving that gives an integer). So there always does exist an a and an n (namely zero) such that `a/2^n` is the exactly correct number. The problem is that `a` has too many significant digits to accommodate in a float.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that the `/` operator in Python always returns a `float` result, even when its operands are `int`. So what you are doing here is:

```
     last_num*(last_num+1))/2  -- this is a float, which has limited precision
int((last_num*(last_num+1))/2) -- now it's an int,
                                  but you can't add missing precision
                                  to what originally had limited precision
```

What you need to do is stay with `int`s throughout your calculation. Use the integer division operator `//` instead:

```
def sum_way2(last_num):
    return (last_num*(last_num+1)) // 2
```

(P.S. if you're looking at an old book or website, which uses Python 2, then its `/` operator did integer division if it had integer operands. That's no longer the case with Python 3.)

Comment: But I got a exact answer when the input data of last_num was 10^9. why can I get exact result last_num is 10^9 and get not exact result last_num is 10^10?

Comment: @user15632158 because all the binary digits of 10^9 can fit inside the significant bits capacity of a floating-point register, but 10^10 is just that bit too many significant digits to fit, so the floating-point representation is an approximation.